# Does the 3M Crystalline tint provide more or less UV protection than the 3M Ceramic IR tint?

Tags: tint

Does the 3M Crystalline tint provide more or less UV protection than the 3M Ceramic IR tint?

---

I am reading conflicting information:

3M™ Crystalline Automotive Window Films:

- https://multimedia.3m.com/mws/media/662303O/3mtm-crystalline-automotive-window-films-brochure.pdf: "blocks 99.9% UV Rays, SPF 1000+"
- [https://www.3m.com/3M/en_US/company-us/all-3m-products/~/3M-Automotive-Window-Film-Crystalline-Series/?N=5002385+3290229310&rt=rud](https://www.3m.com/3M/en_US/company-us/all-3m-products/%7E/3M-Automotive-Window-Film-Crystalline-Series/?N=5002385+3290229310&rt=rud) "Blocks *up to* 99% of ultraviolet (UV) light to provide a total Sun Protection Factor (SPF) of 1000 for you and your passengers.
- https://multimedia.3m.com/mws/media/1161043O/3m-automotive-window-film-crystalline-series-brochure.pdf "Blocking up to 99% of ultraviolet (UV) light, the Crystalline Series provides a total Sun Protection Factor
  (SPF) of 1000."

3M™ Automotive Window Film Ceramic IR Series:

- https://multimedia.3m.com/mws/media/1752329O/ceramic-ir-mini-brochure.pdf: "Blocking up to 99.9% ultraviolet (UV) light"
- https://multimedia.3m.com/mws/media/1161043O/3m-automotive-window-film-crystall: "Up to 99% UV protection (up to SPF 1000)"

It should be easy to see the difference with a UV meter. In terms of health impact, 99.9% protects around ten times more than 99%, since UV damage is cumulative.

---

Since several people have questions the usefulness of blocking UV-A, here are some  motivations:

- http://skincancer.net/clinical/sun-exposure-driving

  > In one study, almost 75% of melanomas were diagnosed on the left side.
- An extreme example of unilateral dermatoheliosis for people who don't get statistics: [Trucker accumulates skin damage on left side of his face after 28 years on the road](https://www.cbsnews.com/news/trucker-accumulates-skin-damage-on-left-side-of-his-face-after-28-years-on-the-road/)

  [image]

---

I have crossposted the question at:

- https://qr.ae/TqpbfK
- https://redd.it/f0xvqp

Comment: It may be a typo, contact Crystalline, no way we could know.

Comment: @Moab thanks, users could know with a UV meter. I'll contact contact Crystalline as well.

Comment: I don't see a big difference between 99% and 99.9% I doubt you can tell the difference after installing it.

Comment: @Moab it should be easy to see the difference with a UV meter. In terms of health impact, 99.9% protects around ten times more than 99%, since UV damage is cumulative.

Comment: So you want one of us to have a calibrated accurate uv meter **AND** both the products available for test... how many beers?

Comment: @SolarMike it is easy to have an accurate UV meter (I have one, got it for 200 USD on Amazon), and I'm assuming many people working in the tinting industry have both products as they are among the most commonly used tints.

Comment: Then go and borrow the two tints and tell us the results.

Comment: @SolarMike yep I might do that indeed

Comment: common glass do block 100% of UV-C and 75-80% of UV-B so it does not matter if the film blocks 99% or 99,9% the result is very close to 100% blocking of UV light.and uv-c does not reach the ground at all.

Comment: @trondhansen common glass does not block UVA.

Comment: UV-A does not damage anything so it is not a problem and it does not get produced in any significant amount in the headlights of cars and UV-A does not get blocked by the film at all.

Comment: @trondhansen UVA causes skin aging and cancer.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultraviolet

Comment: @trondhansen.  https://www.google.com/amp/s/amp.cancer.org/cancer/cancer-causes/radiation-exposure/uv-radiation.html UVA rays have the least energy among UV rays. These rays can cause skin cells to age and can cause some indirect damage to cells' DNA. UVA rays are mainly linked to long-term skin damage such as wrinkles, but they are also thought to play a role in some skin cancers

Comment: Most auto windshields block at least 95% of UV-A and all UV-B, it's hard to see a trickle of UV-A being a major health concern.

Comment: @GdD the side windows matters, as studies have shown.

Comment: Side windows give an average 75% protection from UV-A @FranckDernoncourt, 25% residual UV-A really isn't a concern.

Comment: @GdD that's enough to be harmful. Eg see  https://skincancer.net/clinical/sun-exposure-driving/ "In one study, almost 75% of melanomas were diagnosed on the left side."

Comment: How much time do you spend in the car with the sun on the left @FranckDernoncourt? It's a question of actual risk. The rate of melanoma may be higher on the left but it's still actually very low. Anyway, many car side windows are actually very good at filtering UV-A, you might want to see how yours compare before spending money.

Comment: @GdD 240 hours last year according to Google Maps, and I live in sunny California.

Comment: @SolarMike I have added my own measurements in the answer, please let me know if any question. Anything to help  improve the UV protection is very much welcome.

Comment: Unless you want to spend a lifetime getting your tan on inside the car, it'll likely not matter one iota. You will not get skin cancer in either case, but your fate versus thirst, hunger and boredom might be worse. For this situation, the elders of our clans invented the word "negligible".

Comment: @StianYttervik Since you don't seem concerned with the study I mentioned earlier showing that "almost 75% of melanomas were diagnosed on the left side.", I've added a picture in the question. Doesn't look negligible to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tested the level of UV protection myself with a [Solarmeter® Model 5.7 Sensitive UVA+B Meter](https://www.solarmeter.com/model57.html). I am aware that glass protects against >99% of UV-B radiations, so the usefulness of adding tint to a window from a UV  mostly comes from reducing UV-A radiations.

[image]

Results:

- 3M Crystalline Automotive Window Film 70% tint protects twice more compared to 3M Automotive Window Film Ceramic IR 70% tint (75 vs. 130 µW/cm² when pointing the UV meter directly toward the sun at 11 AM in California on 2020-02-13, with the film in-between). I don't know how many µW/cm² I would have obtained when pointing the UV meter directly toward the sun without any tint in-between: it is at least 2000 µW/cm² but I don't know how far from 2000 (my UV meter only goes up to 2000 as it is designed to be quite sensitive to UV radiations, more than the  [Solarmeter® Model 5.0 Standard UVA+B Meter](https://www.solarmeter.com/model5.html)).
- 3M Crystalline Automotive Window Film 40% tint protects three times more compared to 3M Crystalline Automotive Window Film 70% tint (20 vs. 60 µW/cm² when pointing the UV meter directly toward the sun at 2 PM in California on 2020-02-13, with the tinted car window in-between). Note that with the same car window before tinting, the measurement is 950 µW/cm².

---

According to the 3M customer service:

- Crystalline is nano-carbon type
- IR and crystalline offer the same level of UV protection, which is 99.5% -> Incorrect information according to my measurements above.
- The level of UV protection is independent from the tint level, because the UV protection comes from adhesive and not the film. -> Incorrect information according to my measurements above.
- For both Crystalline and IR, the covered UV are from 320 to 380 nm.  -> According to my measurements above, I think this is incorrect as it seems to cover between 380 nm and 400 nm to some extent as well (I would very much like to know to which extent).

---

Another meter to quantify the level of UV protection of a film: [EDTM SS2450 Solar Spectrum Meter](https://www.edtm.com/index.php/ss2450-solar-spectrum-meter) (more convenient as no need to go under the sun)

[image]

Comment: So, when you think about tints you need to think about **safety** first. These are *tints*, so they will block some natural light. This could be dangerous at night, which is a much higher risk than the residual UV-A rays.

Comment: @GdD good point, one can use a very light tint, e.g. one of the 3M crystalline let 90% of the visible light go through. People typically don't even notice it.