# What's the point of having infrared protection between 1000 nm and 2500 nm when tinting car windows?

Tags: tint

Some tints protect against infrared between 1000 nm and 2500 nm (e.g., [3M™ Ceramic IR Films](https://www.3m.com/3M/en_US/company-us/all-3m-products/~/3M-Automotive-Window-Film-Ceramic-IR-Series/?N=5002385+3289647603&rt=rud)), while some don't (e.g., [3M™ Crystalline Automotive Window Films](https://www.3m.com/3M/en_US/company-us/all-3m-products/~/3M-Automotive-Window-Film-Crystalline-Series/?N=5002385+3290229310&rt=rud)) but still [claim](https://www.qualityautotint.com/crystalline) to protect against 97% of heat-producing infrared.

What's the point of having infrared protection between 1000 nm and 2500 nm when tinting car windows?

Comment: I suppose that is the wavelength that produces 97% of the heat.

Comment: @Moab aside from the heat, is there any point of having infrared protection?

Comment: That's the entire purpose of tint, I don't understand the question.

Comment: See https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/74364/10976